# Slicing based on a condition, else return empty array

Tags: arrays, ruby, conditional-statements, max, slice

Let's say, I have an array: `arr = [12, 34, 56, 38, 29, 91 ...]` and another array: `indices = [ i: i is positive int ]`, where `indices.size` can be zero.

Now,

> I want to slice `arr` starting from the index `i`, where `i` is the max. value of `indices`. If `indices` is empty, then return empty array, `[]`

I have tried the following:

```
arr[ indices.max .. -1 ]
```

which works when `indices` isn't empty, but when it's empty then it throws error: `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`, so I've tried another slice like,

```ruby
arr[ (indices + [-1]).max .. -1 ] # returns last item when indices is empty
# or
arr[ (indices + [-1]).max ... -1 ] # skips last item when indices isn't empty
```

How to do this correctly? (maybe in one line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the array's size as a fallback:

```
arr[(indices.max || arr.size)..-1]
```

Comment: Nice! `()` can be optional, btw

Comment: @vrintle yes, but `indices.max || arr.size..-1` looks more like `(indices.max) || (arr.size..-1)` to me due to the spacing. (and I dislike adding spaces around `..`)

Comment: If you dislike spaces around ranges, then in this specific case, you can omit `-1` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that the indices is empty. I would check if `indices.max` is not empty and then use your code snippet. Example:

```
indices.empty? ? [] : arr[ indices.max .. -1 ]
```

If you use it, you must met some preconditions first:

- arr isn't nil
- indices isn't nil

Comment: I think it is sufficient (and more efficient) to check just `indices.empty?` instead of `indices.max`, because `indices.max` can only be nil if `indices` is empty.

Comment: Good advise. I have changed my previous answer.

Comment: We know that `arr` and `indices` are arrays, so neither can equal `nil`. Your answer reads well, imo. btw, it's "advice". ("advise" is a verb.)